# How to overload operator ==?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have class A
how to overload operator == to perform

```
A a,b,c;
if (a==b==c) {}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You're much better off just using `(a == b && a == c)`. If you really want that kind of syntax, you'll gonna need some very ugly hacks.

Comment: Do you just want a `operator==` or something can implement `a==b==c`?

Comment: You need 2 operator==, one that takes 2 A and returns a B that remembers one of its arguments and the result of the first comparison, and one that takes a B and an A and returns a B. And B is contextually convertible to bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very short answer: **NO!**
Slightly longer answer: Don't try this.

Explanation: Every C++ programmer is used to have the comparison operator return a bool or something convertible to bool. Just because it's natural to type things like `if (a==b)`.
So if the expression `a==b` returns a bool `x`, then `a==b==c` would mean comparing `x` with `c`. Which makes no sense at all. Even if you get it to compile, e.g. comparing ints that way, it would not yield the result you expect.

So, while there *technically* I can think of a solution to what you seem to want (compare if all three are equal), the right thing to do is how it is always done in C++: logically chain binary comparisons:

```
if (a==b && b==c) {}
```

---

for the ones who wonder about the "technical doable but oh so ugly" solution:
(**DON'T DO THIS IN REAL WORLD USE!** You should get fired if you do.)

```
template <class T>
struct multiCompareProxy {
  bool b;
  T const& t;

  explicit operator bool() const {return b;}
  multiCompareProxy operator==(T const& rhs) {
    return {b && t.equals(rhs), t};
  }
};

template <class T>
multiCompareProxy<T> operator==(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
  return {lhs.equals(rhs), lhs};
}
```

A class now just has to overload the `euqals` method for this to work: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc6c3e7a8b4930e0)

Comment: `template <class T> multiCompareProxy<T> operator==(T const& lhs, T const& rhs)` / "just has to overload the equals..." if you picked a more obscure name than `equals` and had an `enable_if` it'd be a reasonable approach, but as is it could interfere with (compiler error on) a lot of other comparisons for classes that have no interest in this kind of comparison logic, nor any `equals` function.

Comment: Since this is a template, it will only be considered by the compiler if objects are compared whose class has no own overloaded `op==`. Nevertheless I agree that it can be refined a bit to not interfere with other classes not meant for this kind of comparison. But since it is only a toy implementation that never should be set free I think it is sufficient to produce a working sandbox example.

Comment: "...class has no own overloaded op==" unless the `==` for the class is itself a template.  Anyway - agree it's nice to allude to what's worth exploring.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason you *really* wanted to do this, you'd need a proxy object like so:

```
struct A {};
struct Proxy {};

Proxy operator==(const A& a, const A& b) {
    return {};
}

bool operator==(const Proxy& p, const A& b) {
    return true;
}

bool operator==(const A& a, const Proxy& p) {
    return true;
}


#include <iostream>

int main() {
    A a, b, c;
    if(a == b == c) {
        std::cout << "Bad.\n";
    }
}
```

But *don't* do this. Use `(a == b) && (a == c)` like everyone else.

Comment: This would obviously return true for every ternary comparison, regardless of the contents ;-)

Comment: @ArneMertz I'm showcasing! I don't know what logic the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, and it's *very occasionally* useful as a kind of domain-specific language (DSL) for matching the notation expected by non-C++-programmers, but it should be studiously avoided for other uses as it'll confound (and annoy) programmers working on the code if this is used willy-nilly.

```
class A
{
    // ...

    bool equals(const A& rhs) const { return ... }

    struct X
    {
        X(const A& a, bool b) : a_(a), b_(b) { }
        X& operator==(const A& rhs) const { b_ &= a_.equals(rhs); return *this; }

        explicit operator bool() const { return b_; }
        // remove explicit pre C++11 / consider making it operator void*() ...

        const A& a_;
        mutable bool b_;
    };

    X A::operator==(const A& rhs) const
    {
        return X(*this, equals(rhs));
    }
};
```

(You might prefer standalone functions if you have implicit constructors).

The same kind of proxy-using hackery allows all manner of unexpected notations like `3 < x < 9` and `x == a1 || a2 || a3`... again, avoid them unless it'll make a huge difference to the maintainers of the code where they'll be used (and ideally that code will have very clear boundaries from the other C++ code in your system).

As an example of good uses of such techniques, consider the boost spirit library and it's unusual use of a lot of operators to provide something approximating BNF notation....

Comment: Missing `const` on `a_`, no reason to make `b_` mutable. +`explicit` in C++11.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: good calls on the `const` and `explicit`.  `b_` is mutable because X will be a temporary so `operator==` should be `const`.  I could have returned another temporary `X` but figured that challenged the optimiser for no good reason....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (minus the possibility of an ugly hack) overload `operator==(...)` to work as you have specified.

If you think about what it would do `a == b` would become either true or false (a bool), then you would have `(<bool> == c)` left. The proper way to do what you are looking to do would be some form of `(a==b) && (b==c)`.

There are times when you can overload an operator to work as you describe, but it would have to return the same type that it takes. An example would be:

```
class A
{
  A& operator+=(A const& rhs)
  {
     // operator logic
     return *this;
  }
}
```

This case works because with `a += b += c`, you would perform `(b += c)` which would return an `A&`, which the remaining `a.operator+=(...)` accepts as an argument.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you can, with some horrible proxy class. But I definitely wouldn't

Comment: True enough. Many things are possible, but that doesn't mean they should be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator==(T const & a, T const & b) {
     return /*boolean expr*/
}
```

if you have a class you can do:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    bool operator==(T const & rhs) const {
       return /*boolean expr*/
    }
}
```

And don't use == twice in a row, you can't, do:

```
a == b && b == c
```

Comment: He asks for the behavior a == b == c, which your solution does not provide.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing all the question. Besides that, that didn't make my reply useless. He wants to overload (but he didn´t know the syntax correctly).

Comment: He specifically states he wants to overload it **to perform** the given syntax.

Comment: ok, well. Rereading I see you are right about that. I just hope that overloading operator== was a useful hint to semantically perform what he wanted. I voted you up.

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
```

And use it twice with and operation.